# .zip file gets converted to .bin file while sending the email in java

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am trying to send mail using below snippet with the `zip file` as attachment,I am able to send the email but the attachment which is zip file gets converted to some `.bin` file.
Do I need to set some properties?
Why zip file gets converted to .bin file?

```
Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

            Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            mailSession.setDebug(true);
            Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            message.setSubject("HTML  mail with images");
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("b@gmail.com"));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                 new InternetAddress("a@gmail.com"));
            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

            // first part  (the html)
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String htmlText = "PFA Query Output.";
            messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");

            // add it
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // second part (the image)
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(zipFilePath);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");

            // add it
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // put everything together
            message.setContent(multipart);

            transport.connect();
            transport.sendMessage(message,
                message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            transport.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>")` if you're not sending image.

Add follwing statement set attachment filename,

```
  messageBodyPart.setFileName(zipFilePath);
```

Comment: Maybe also `messageBodyPart.setContent(messageBodyPart, "application/zip");`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
 DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(zipFilePath);
```

try

```
 DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(new File(zipFilePath));
```

Also try removing,

```
 messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");
```