# Images are converted to .bin files in java-mail

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send a mail which has html contents[Includes Images] using javamail API , when ever I try to send the mail through unit test , its working as excepted meaning html contents are getting delivered properly but when I use the same code in application [When running inside tomcat server] , I getting all the image file as bin files as ATT00005.bin & so on.. 
  Here is my code

```
public void sendMail(String userName, String test_name, String toaddress,
            String ccaddress, String status, int total_marks, String msg,
            String filepath) throws MessagingException, AddressException {  
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        InternetAddress ccaddressTo = new InternetAddress(ccaddress);
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toaddress));
        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            String temp1 = "<HTML><BODY><center><TABLE border=0><TR><TD ><img src=\"cid:image1\" border=0></TD>";
            String temp2 = "</TR><TR><TD><table width=100%  border=0><tr align=center><td><img src=\"cid:image2\" "
                    + "border=0 width=340 height=32></td>";
            String temp3 = "<tr ></tr ><td align=center>Awarded To   </td><tr ></tr ><td align=center>"
                    + userName
                    + "</td><tr ></tr ><td align=center> <img src=\"cid:image3\" border=0 width=270 height=32> </td>";
            String temp4 = "</tr> </tr > <td align=center>TEST CERTIFICATION PROGRAM    </td>  </tr><tr><td align=\"center\">Test name : "
                    + test_name
                    + "</td></tr></table></td></tr><TR><TD>"
                    + "<img src=\"cid:image4\" border=0 ></TD></TR> </TABLE> </center> </body></HTML>";

            String htmlText = temp1 + temp2 + temp3 + temp4;
            messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds1 = new FileDataSource(filepath + "b1.jpg");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds1));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image1>");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds2 = new FileDataSource(filepath + "cert.gif");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds2));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image2>");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds3 = new FileDataSource(filepath + "cer2.gif");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds3));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image3>");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds4 = new FileDataSource(filepath + "b3.jpg");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds4));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image4>");

            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        } else {
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            messageBodyPart.setText("Hello " + userName + ",\n" + msg);

        }
        message.setContent(multipart);

        // Send the message
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(SMTP_HOST_NAME, null, null);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
}
```

I know some asked the same question like this here [.zip file gets converted to .bin file while sending the email in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554847/zip-file-gets-converted-to-bin-file-while-sending-the-email-in-java) . But my problem is the same code working when used junit [Or in application with main method] but not when the application is running on tomcat server . What I am doing wrong . Thanks in advance...

Comment: Might it be that a different javamail implementation is used when you run your code on tomcat server?

Comment: I don't think so because I don't any other application in my tomcat server.
UPDATE : Checked that by debugging , it is using the same jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify a name, if you do not want the system to automatically provide one :

```
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource fds1 = new FileDataSource(filepath + "b1.jpg");
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds1));
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image1>");
messageBodyPart.setFileName(filepath + "b1.jpg");            // <= HERE
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

When you set the `dataHandler` in `messageBodyPart`, you only tell the javamail machinery where are the bytes you want to send. Or more exactely, this is only what javamail understands. But there is another field in `messageBodyPart` : the `fileName`. For javamail the original name and the name used in the message are totally unrelated which can be source of brain hurt first time we use it ...

Comment: Awesome !!!! That's working . But can you please explain me what happening here , what is the problem ?

Comment: Note that you can make this simpler by using the attachFile method on MimeBodyPart.